# Collections.synchronizedMap( ) returns class cast exception where as normal map works fine

Tags: java, collections

When i cast Collections.synchronizedMap( ) to hash map it returns class cast exception but when i cast Map to hash map it works fine.

As per my understanding Collections.synchronizedMap( ) also returns map .

Then Why i am getting this exception .

How to over come it.

Example code

```
 public class Main_1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Map m = new HashMap();
    m.put("sachin", "sacjdeva");
     // Throws exception here 
    HashMap hm = (HashMap) Collections.synchronizedMap(m);
    //No exception
    HashMap hm = (HashMap)(m)
    System.out.println(hm);
   }
 }
```

**Ok if its  synchronizedMap and throws class cast exception can i convert this SynchronizedMap to HashMap.**

Comment: `Map` is an interface but `HashMap` is implementation type. So better to cast it to `Map`

Comment: You cannot cast an Interface to an implementing-interface class, you can invoke the hashmap constructor giving that map as input, instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Dynamic and Static type assignments in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504714/difference-between-dynamic-and-static-type-assignments-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.synchronizedMap(m)` doesn't return a `HashMap`, so you can't cast it to `HashMap`. It returns a `SynchronizedMap` instance.

You can assign it to a `Map` :

```
Map smap = Collections.synchronizedMap(m);
```

In your "normal Map" example :

```
HashMap hm = (HashMap)(m);
```

is not a "normal Map". There is no such thing as "normal Map".

You assign a `HashMap` instance to it here :

```
Map m = new HashMap();
```

which is the only reason you can later cast it to `HashMap`.

Comment: I know i does not return hash map it returns only map .

Comment: @ShowStopper I'm not just referring to the return type of that method, which is `Map`, I'm referring to the actual `Map` implementation that this method returns, which is `SynchronizedMap`, and therefore can't be cast to `HashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

It returns an instance of `Map`, i.e. an instance of a class (that you don't need to know) that implements the `Map` interface. You don't need to cast it to `HashMap`, which is **another** class implementing the same `Map` interface.

```
HashMap hm = (HashMap)(m)
```

works only because the actual concrete class of `m` is HashMap. It wouldn't work if you initialized `m` with

```
Map m = new TreeMap();
```

for example.

You should program to interfaces rather than programming to concrete types. Your variable should be of type `Map`. You should also avoid using raw types, and specify the generic parameters of the map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
m.put("sachin", "sacjdeva");
Map<String, String> synchronizedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is interface. `HashMap` is one implementation, `SynchronizedMap` is another implementation.

`SynchronizedMap` is not a `HashMap`, so you cannot cast it to it.

`HashMap` is a `HashMap`, so you can cast it.

In your example it is better to cast to `Map` if you need, as it would allow you to work with any implementation.

Comment: SynchronizedMap is not an implementation, but a method. Pls see [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map))

Comment: It is an implementation. Take a look at the method's implementation - it returns a `SynchronizedMap` class

Answer (score 0):

`Hashmap` is not synchronized so it can't be cast to Synchronized Map while `Map` is an `interface` so what ever type of synchronized Map returned it implements `Map` so can be caseted to `Map`

Answer (score 0):

`SynchronizedMap` returns a different implementation than `HashMap` implementation, so you can't cast it to `HashMap`.

But you can do this:

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
m.put("sachin", "sacjdeva");

Map<String, String> hm = Collections.synchronizedMap(m);
```

Comment: Err no, you can't. This still casts the synchronized Map to HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Collections.synchronizedMap(Map) returns an instance of SynchronizedMap which is an inner class of Collections class. Following piece of code will get the actual class name being returned.

```
System.out.println(Collections.synchronizedMap(m).getClass().getName());
```

SynchronizedMap implements the Map interface but it is not a subclass of HashMap. So casting SynchronizedMap to HashMap will cause ClassCastException.