# How to know the Dynamic type of a class?

Tags: java

My question is, how, or if its possible, to know the dynamic type of an object in the compilator.
I have this data

```
public abstract class accommodation;
public class Hotel extends accomodation;
public class Cabin extends accomodation;
accomodation [] array=  new accomodation[x];
```

My actual problem is, can i get an array with only hotels from this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Dynamic and Static type assignments in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504714/difference-between-dynamic-and-static-type-assignments-in-java)

Comment: You can use `if (a instanceof Hotel)` (on each element) to filter the array.

Comment: I would say that your design may have a problem if you really think you have this need.  Most of the time, it is preferable to code to an interface, and deal with general accommodation objects rather than a specific subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a few ways to do this.  One is to use the `getClass()` method.  Because this is defined in the `Object` class, it can be called on every Java object.

```
System.out.println(myObject.getClass());
```

or even

```
if (myObject.getClass() == MyClass.class)
```

But if you only want to know whether an object is an instance of a particular class, you can write

```
if (myObject instanceof MyType)
```

which will return `true` if the class of `myObject` is `MyType` or any subtype thereof.  You can use either an interface or a class for `MyType` here - even an abstract class.

However, as Tim pointed out in the comments, often there are better ways to design your program than relying on one of these ways of checking the class of an object.  Careful use of polymorphism reduces the need for either of these.

Comment: Just to point it, i edited my question. Forgot to mention that accomodation is an abstract class.
However, "myObject" is going to point the dynamic type, right? The type that has been used to create the object, not to declare the variable.
So.. This should works?
if (array[index] instanceof Hotel) -> add to new array

Comment: Yes, `if (array[index] instanceof Hotel)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `filter` and `map` to first filter out all the objects that are `Hotel`s, and cast to `Hotel`.

```
Arrays.stream(array)
    .filter(x -> x instanceof Hotel)
    .map(x -> (Hotel)x)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```